# CSS/JQuery: Menu List Titles Drop Down When Hovering Over Another List Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

Whenever I hover over the "blog" option, I am supposed to see a list of 3 items. The hover itself functions perfectly: the list children appear below the list item. However, the div that the menu items are in expands down, and the menu item titles go down to the very bottom of the div, while the hovered list item stays in the original position. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

CODE:

```js
    //dropdown hover code
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    
     //hover menu bar list
     $('li').hover(function()
     {
      //find children of list items
      //add stop function to stop hover queue
      $(this).find('ul>li').stop().fadeToggle(300);
     });
     //end dropdown hover
    
     //menu background color hover
     $('a').css('background-color', 'white').hover(function()
     {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'pink');
     },
     function()
     {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
     });
     //end background color hover
    
    });
    //end ready function
```

```css
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
     #dropdown_menu li {
      display: block !important;
      border: 1px solid black !important;
      border-right: none !important;
      border-left: none !important;
    
     }
    
     #title_img_container {
      margin-bottom: 10%;
     }
    
     #title_container {
      margin-top: 0 !important;
      margin-bottom: 10%;
      position: relative !important;
     }
    
     #dropdown_menu li {
      border-bottom: none !important;
    
     }
    }
    
    /*Change size of title div at 650px*/
    @media (max-width: 650px) {
     #title_container {
      font-size: 3em !important;
     }
    }
    
    /*Change size of title img at 807px*/
    @media (min-width: 807px) {
     #title_img_container {
      margin-top: 3%;
     }
    
     #title_img {
      max-width: 650px;
      height: auto;
     }
    }
    
    /*Change size of title img at 1300px*/
    @media (min-width: 1300px) {
     #title_img {
      max-width: 600px;
      max-height: 700px;
     }
    }
    
    body {
     /*background-color: #dee1e5;*/
     background-image: url("./../img/title_chevron.jpg");
     letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
    
    #title_img_container {
     max-width: 100%;
     height: auto;
    }
    
    #title_img {
     border: solid 1px black; 
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 5px #888888;
    }
    
    #title_container {
     border: solid 2px black;
     width: 100%;
     font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
     font-size: 5em;
     color: gold;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: white; 
    }
    
    #menu_container {
     font-size: 30px;
    }
    
    #img_and_content {
     margin: 5%;
    }
    
    #dropdown_menu,
    #dropdown_menu ul {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
    }
    
    #dropdown_menu li{
     display: inline-block;
    }
    
    #dropdown_menu a {
     padding: 10px 20px;
     display: block;
     color: inherit;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #dropdown_menu ul li {
     display: none;
     background-color: #afdbcd !important;
     vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    li a {
     color: gold;
    }
    
    #main_page_container {
     padding: 2% 5% 2% 5%;
     border: black 1px solid;
     font-family: 'Helvetica', Arial;
     background-color: white;
    }
    
    #content_title {
     font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    }
    
    #footer_container {
     color: black;
     text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--FONTS-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">

<!--TITLE DIV-->
<div id="title_container">YOUR NAME
  <!--MENU DIV-->
  <div id="menu_container">
    <!--DROPDOWN MENU-->
    <ul id="dropdown_menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
      <li><a href="final_about.html">About</a></li> 
      <!--HOVER MENU OPTIONS-->
      <li class="blogs"><a href="#">Blogs</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="final_motherhood.html">Motherhood</a></li>
          <li><a href="final_fitness.html">Fitness</a></li>
          <li><a href="final_marriage.html">Marriage and Family</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!--END HOVER MENU OPTIONS-->
      <li><a href="final_contact.html">Contact</a></li>   
    </ul>
    <!--END DROPDOWN MENU-->
  </div>
  <!--END MENU DIV-->
</div>
<!--END TITLE DIV-->

<!--IMG AND CONTENT CONTAINER-->
<div id="img_and_content" class="container-fluid">
  <!--ROW DIV-->
  <div class="row">
    <!--TITLE IMG DIV-->
    <div id="title_img_container" class="col-md-6">
      <img id="title_img" src="./img/title_img.jpg">
    </div>
    <!--END TITLE IMG DIV-->

    <!--MAIN PAGE DIV-->
    <div id="main_page_container" class="col-md-6">
      <h1 id="content_title">Insert Title Here . . .</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eget viverra ipsum. 
    </div>
    <!--END MAIN PAGE DIV-->
  </div>
  <!--END ROW DIV-->
</div>
<!--END IMG AND CONTENT CONTAINER-->


<!--FOOTER DIV-->
<div id="footer_container">
  &copy; 2018 Erika Marie McBride | Site by Kelly Catbagan
</div>
<!--FOOTER DIV-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your CSS to handle the sub menu of Blogs, real simple fix for when not in mobile version. I'm sure there are other ways to handle this as well. In mobile view, your sub-menu shows by default. May want to look at doing a click event to toggle showing/hiding it in mobile?

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  li.blogs ul {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    z-index: 1000;
  }
}
```

Also, FYI, you are including the jQuery library source more than once in your HTML, which isn't necessary. I also removed references to your local JS and IMG files as well for this example snippet..

```js
//dropdown hover code
$(document).ready(function() {

  //hover menu bar list
  $('li').hover(function() {
    //find children of list items
    //add stop function to stop hover queue
    $(this).find('ul>li').stop().fadeToggle(300);
  });
  //end dropdown hover

  //menu background color hover
  $('a').css('background-color', 'white').hover(function() {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'pink');
    },
    function() {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    });
  //end background color hover

});
//end ready function
```

```css
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #dropdown_menu li {
    display: block !important;
    border: 1px solid black !important;
    border-right: none !important;
    border-left: none !important;
  }
  #title_img_container {
    margin-bottom: 10%;
  }
  #title_container {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    position: relative !important;
  }
  #dropdown_menu li {
    border-bottom: none !important;
  }
}


/*Change size of title div at 650px*/

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  #title_container {
    font-size: 3em !important;
  }
}


/*Change size of title img at 807px*/

@media (min-width: 807px) {
  #title_img_container {
    margin-top: 3%;
  }
  #title_img {
    max-width: 650px;
    height: auto;
  }
}


/*Change size of title img at 1300px*/

@media (min-width: 1300px) {
  #title_img {
    max-width: 600px;
    max-height: 700px;
  }
}

body {
  /*background-color: #dee1e5;*/
  background-image: url("./../img/title_chevron.jpg");
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#title_img_container {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#title_img {
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 5px #888888;
}

#title_container {
  border: solid 2px black;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: gold;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}

#menu_container {
  font-size: 30px;
}

#img_and_content {
  margin: 5%;
}

#dropdown_menu,
#dropdown_menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#dropdown_menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#dropdown_menu a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: block;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#dropdown_menu ul li {
  display: none;
  background-color: #afdbcd !important;
  vertical-align: top;
}

li a {
  color: gold;
}

#main_page_container {
  padding: 2% 5% 2% 5%;
  border: black 1px solid;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', Arial;
  background-color: white;
}

#content_title {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}

#footer_container {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  li.blogs ul {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    z-index: 1000;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <!--RESPONSIVE SETUP-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!--FONTS-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>YOUR NAME</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--TITLE DIV-->
  <div id="title_container">YOUR NAME
    <!--MENU DIV-->
    <div id="menu_container">
      <!--DROPDOWN MENU-->
      <ul id="dropdown_menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="final_about.html">About</a></li>
        <!--HOVER MENU OPTIONS-->
        <li class="blogs"><a href="#">Blogs</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="final_motherhood.html">Motherhood</a></li>
            <li><a href="final_fitness.html">Fitness</a></li>
            <li><a href="final_marriage.html">Marriage and Family</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!--END HOVER MENU OPTIONS-->
        <li><a href="final_contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <!--END DROPDOWN MENU-->
    </div>
    <!--END MENU DIV-->
  </div>
  <!--END TITLE DIV-->

  <!--IMG AND CONTENT CONTAINER-->
  <div id="img_and_content" class="container-fluid">
    <!--ROW DIV-->
    <div class="row">
      <!--TITLE IMG DIV-->
      <div id="title_img_container" class="col-md-6">
      </div>
      <!--END TITLE IMG DIV-->

      <!--MAIN PAGE DIV-->
      <div id="main_page_container" class="col-md-6">
        <h1 id="content_title">Insert Title Here . . .</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eget viverra ipsum.
      </div>
      <!--END MAIN PAGE DIV-->
    </div>
    <!--END ROW DIV-->
  </div>
  <!--END IMG AND CONTENT CONTAINER-->


  <!--FOOTER DIV-->
  <div id="footer_container">
    &copy; 2018 Erika Marie McBride | Site by Kelly Catbagan
  </div>
  <!--FOOTER DIV-->


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Woodrow! I've been confused by this since yesterday! Thank you very much for your help, as well as your great observation!